# Is it possible to call a function in a parent component from a child component in Flex?

Tags: parent-child, flex3

I need to call a function located in the parent component and make the call from the child component in Flex 3.  Is there a way to access functions in the parent component from the child component?  I know I can dispatch an event in the child and add a listener in the parent to call the function, but just wanted to know if could also directly call a parent function from a child.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use parentApplication

For example... if i have a main.mxml that calls a component we'll call child.mxml, i can call functions in main from within child by doing the following:

```
parentApplication.parentsFunctionName(parameters);
```